# How do I create a hide and show navigation bar in html5 using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, navigationbar

i am creating a mobile fashion magazine app and I want to create a navigation bar button so that when people press the button the navigation is shown and when you press it again the navigation bar hides. Something like this example 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mg1WkjJgfEU

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the simpliest way is to add toggle for button click/touch event, e.g:

```
<... onclick="$('#navigation_bar').toggle()">
```

You can read about jquery toggle [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)